# How to set different map layers for different zoom levels using ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have created a layer using "clip" tool in ArcMap.

[image]

I have another layer in TOC too. whichis the same area in "clip" Layer with more polygons.

[image]

In my web map application (javaScript API) Is there any way to set these layers in a way that when I zoom in I get more details like image2 and by zooming out I get polygons in image1.

Answer (score 2):

To change the displayed layer at different scales you should set the [scale range](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000008000000). This can either be done on the source data before publishing to ArcGIS server with the layer [properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000008000000) > general > scale range option or can be done in code by setting the Max and Min scales of the layer using [SetScaleRange](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#setscalerange)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using some custom code.

The Map has a [Zoom start](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#zoom-start) event, which fires when a user commences zooming.
You can listen to this event in your code, and then change the layer in the map to show data from the appropriate service.